# Is it possible to use d3 and create line/curve like vis.js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, vis.js

I'm using d3 to create network graph with circles & lines. while using d3, lines are straight, i was wondering if it is possible to achieve more flex line like vis.js, adding pic for demonstration:

d3:
[image]

Vis.js:

[image]

Comment: Yes, I believe you can do that. Take a look at this [example](https://observablehq.com/@d3/hierarchical-edge-bundling). It might help you.

Comment: yes, check out what a [bezier curve](http://bl.ocks.org/mforando/57e32915606a46ae18eeb58a3e1ea0e2) is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

d3 can do all kind of visualisation. What are you asking it is line interpolation.
Out of the box the box d3 supports

- linear
- List item
- step-before
- step-after
- basis
- basis-open
- basis-closed
- bundle
- cardinal
- cardinal-open
- cardinal-closed
- monotone

There two links with interpolation comparisons
- https://bl.ocks.org/emmasaunders/f7178ed715a601c5b2c458a2c7093f78
- https://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/ced1b9b18bd8192d2c898884033b5529

These interpolations available from the box, but not limited to it. You can write your own interpolation on d3,
f.e. https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3310323

Have added snipped of the code. Alternatively you may use d3.svg.diagonal()

```js
let curveData = [{ x: 190, y: 100 }, { x: 269, y: 50 }, { x: 360, y: 150 }];
let edge = d3.select('svg').append('g').attr('class', 'g1');
let edge2 = d3.select('svg').append('g').attr('class', 'g2');

var line11 = d3.svg.line()
  .x(function(d) { return (d.x ) })
  .y(function(d) { return (d.y ) })
  .interpolate('cardinal');

let diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
 .source(function (d) { return { x: d[0].y, y: d[0].x }; })            
 .target(function (d) { return { x: d[d.length - 1].y, y: d[d.length - 1].x }; })
 .projection(function (d) { return [d.y, d.x]; });
   
d3.select('.g1')
  .datum(curveData)
  .append('path')
  .attr('class', 'link')
  .attr('d', diagonal)
  .attr('stroke', 'red')
  .attr('stroke-width', 3)
  .attr('fill', 'none');

d3.select('.g2')
  .datum(curveData)
  .append('path')
  .attr('class', 'link')
  .attr('d', line11)
  .attr('stroke', 'blue')
  .attr('stroke-width', 2)
  .attr('fill', 'none');
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.12/d3.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <svg width=500 height=500></svg>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: hm... so seems like there isn't something I can use right away such in vis.js right? seems like vis.js made these line very flex and nice

Comment: @USer22999299 d3 is library with math for data visualisation first. It totally depends on chart you are using. If there is already line - you may change interpolation method. It totally depends on chart you are working. If you can share code - I may help you

Comment: I'm building a graph, currently, I have a few circles and lines between them to connect the graph component. In that case all I need is line interpolation?

Comment: Yeap.take a look https://bocoup.com/blog/improving-d3-path-animation. It is just few lines of code